# FDR for Bayes Factors

Tags: permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

I have a dataset, 2 models $M_0$ and $M_1$. Most of my events belong to model $M_0$, so I detect events, belonging to $M_1$, only if the corresponding Bayes factor is bigger than 20.

So far so good, I need to provide some guarantee on FDR. I permute the dataset a lot of times (just enough for Bonferroni to be significant at least once), and since I have also simulated data, I know that there is no covariance, so permutations are correct for sure. Then I detect events belonging to $M_1$ using the same threshold of 20 and form a null distribution of Bayes factors.

Then I calculate p-values based on this distribution (1 + number of times the test statistic exceed the observed test statistic) / (size of the generated distribution of detected Bayes factors greater then threshold). Then, Benjamini-Hochberg, q-values < 0.05.

But the observed FDR is far from 0.05! It is really inflated.

The questions:

1) is it correct to make permutation test like this - only events > 20 BF included?

2) are there smarter ways to control FDR for Bayes factors? Note - everything is OK for simulated data, but I'd like to be at least semi-non-parametric in FDR estimations (which can be achieved with permutations) since real data has quite a lot of outliers.

3) General question: let's say we have performed $n$ tests, but we decided that only tests with some restriction rule are suitable for us: say, only test with effect size more than $x$, or tests with p-value less than $0.05$. Is it correct to cut a null distribution according to the new restriction and perform FDR correction based on restricted null and only tests that were pre-selected with this criteria?